# What does "Restore from iCloud Backup" currently NOT restore? (Fail to preserve/discard/lose/delete?)

Tags: iphone, backup, restore

What does "Restore from iCloud Backup" currently NOT restore?  Is restore from local backup *more* or *less*, complete?

(My intention is for the answer to stay up to date, SE-style; I know this answer has changed over time and don't know what the current answer is.)

My experience suggests I'll have to enter my Apple ID password a bunch of times.  (So I'll copy it into the clipboard as soon as I can after a restore so I can paste it as needed.)

As I recall, several apps that were on a previous iPhone and I don't think I ever uninstalled weren't installed on the new one I restored to.  But I'm not certain.

I believe a some of my old iMessage discussions are gone, but most aren't.  I'd like to better understand what doesn't survive and why.  I have some old local backups and wonder if there's a tool for restoring those old conversations back into Messages.

I would guess that my list of open apps isn't restored, so things that I should keep running at all the time, like the Tile App, Groundwire, would need to be restarted.

Interestingly, my new phone does display signal strength in dB instead of bars, using some trick I used on a previous phone long ago.  (Update: That feature didn't survive a more recent upgrade.)

From reading Apple's iOS Security Guide, I know some functionality isn't restored iff the new phone and the old phone aren't the same phone.  What about keys, etc in apps like Signal...?

(Info about what's restored when an iPad backup is restored to an iPhone or vice versa would be an added plus, but is probably better for another question.)